# Conseguir datos de mysql que están en formato json y escribirlos en php

Tags: php, mysql, json

Estoy intentando conseguir datos de mysql que están en formato json y escribirlos en php. Thengo un php que le llamo con el id de la persona que quiero que muestre. Es decir el url es:
"http\localhost:8888\php.dispatch.php?id=20"
por ejemplo. Lo que yo quiero hacer es coger ese id, encontrr la persona y mostrar la col,iumna "form" que es un json. he hecho esto:

```
<?php

require '/home/ddbb/db.php';

$fetchData = fetch_data();

function fetch_data(){
$query = "SELECT * FROM formulario_freelance WHERE id =39";

$conn = new mysqli();
$result =  $conn->query($query);

print_r($result );
if($result == true){ 
 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $row= mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return $row;
 } else {
   return "No Data Found"; 
 }
}else   return "result= false"; 
}


$output = json_encode(($fetchData));
print_r($output);


?>
```

pero el $output es null. No se como hacer para que no sea null el output. Lo que me sale en la consola es:  "result = false";

Estos son los errores que me salen:

```
 PHP Warning:  mysqli::query(): invalid object or resource mysqli\n in /home/php/dispatch.php on line 16
```

Comment: Todo apunta a que la consulta es errónea. El método query te devuelve false y tú devuelves la cadena. Las comillas en la tabla y en el nombre del campo son erróneas. En vez de devolver el ese valor mejor será que muestres el error que ha dado mysqli. Mira en los métodos mysqli alguno para devolver errores, o incluso metelo en un try/catch y resuelve el error.

Comment: La cosa es que no se cuál es el error. Por eso estoy preguntando

Comment: ¿Qué arroja esto ejecutado directamente en la base de datos: `SELECT * FROM formulario_freelance WHERE id =39`? De todos modos, falta contexto en la pregunta. Hablas de que pasas un valor por URL y no muestras nada al respecto, sino una consulta fija. Tu función tampoco está completa, no la cierras al final y esto no tiene sentido: `$output = json_encode(($fetchData));`. Además, `mysqli_fetch_all` no funciona en algunos contextos. Convendría que actives/revises el log de errores.

Comment: require '/home/ddbb/db.php';

Comment: Para ver los errores, puedes poner estas tres líneas **provisionalmente** al inicio de tu script PHP: `ini_set('display_errors', '1');
 ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` Luego lo guardas e intentas de nuevo. Ahora deberás ver los mensajes de eror, si no los entiendes, puedes ponerlos en la pregunta pulsando en [edit]. El hecho es que ese código puede estar fallando por muchos motivos y convendría saber con exactitud qué es lo que falla. Si aprendes a **depurar** el código, te vas a ahorrar muuuuchas horas y muuuuchos dolores de cabeza.

Comment: Ya he puesto los errores

Comment: Se ve con claridad que tienes problemas en `dispatch.php`, ¿podrías mostrarnos ese archivo, cambiando cualquier información sensible por datos ficticios? ¿Puedes explicarnos cómo se relaciona `dispatch.php` con el código que nos muestras en la pregunta?

Comment: en el archivo dispatch.php tengo el codigo que he puesto arriba, nada más

Comment: ¿Cuál es la línea `29` de ese archivo? Dice que hay una variable `$mysqli` no definida, pero no veo que uses una variable llamada`$mysqli` en ninguna parte. Observa la ruta de los archivos en los mensajes de error. ¿No nos estarás mostrando otro archivo distinto en la pregunta?

Comment: Además, esto no tiene sentido: `$conn = new mysqli();` eso no conecta a la base de datos, faltan los parámetros para la conexión, supongo que la conexión la deberías tomar desde `db.php`, usando el nombre de variable que le hayas dado allí, por eso haces `require` de ese archivo, ¿no?

Comment: Ya lo he cambiado pero no me aparece naada

Comment: Aquí estarías creando una conexión nula: `$conn = new mysqli();` debes usar la conexión que creas en `db.php` sin más, asumiendo que se crea correctamente, con las credenciales necesarias como usario, password, etc. ¿Cómo se llama la conexión allí?